# Push safari browser in uinavigationcontroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Can I push the safari browser in my `UINavigationController`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot open the browser within the app. You can either use a [`UIWebView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instead which you can place in a view or open the browser separately by using

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:someUrl];
```

Comment: I have to use safari because I am using apple store urls . And I am using
[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:someUrl];
And I wanted to embedded safari in the navigator but it seems impossible

Comment: That's why apple invented UIWebView.  Sure it's not as full-featured and finished as mobile safari, but you can put the effort in to make it that way.

Answer (score 2):

Create a UIViewController with a fullscreen UIWebView on it and load "http://google.com" in it when the view appears, that'll be a same safari browser, but only one tab.